# CASE for calculating quantity

Tags: sql

Hello Everybody ,

I have a requirement, where I need to calculate `Quantity` for two cases:

- case 1:

  ```
  if (vouchernumber starts with letter `'A%' or 'B%'` ) then 
       Quantity must be Quantity*-1
  ```
- case 2:

  ```
  if (vouchernumber starts with letter `'C%'` ) then 
       Quantity is zero
  ```

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: Why don't just start writing this using `case` statement almost exactly as you've described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a `CASE` expression containing the logic you described:

```
SELECT vouchernumber,
       CASE WHEN vouchernumber LIKE 'A%' OR vouchernumber LIKE 'B%' THEN -1*Quantity
            WHEN vouchernumber LIKE 'C%' THEN 0
            ELSE <some other condition...>
       END
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: instead of display 0[ZERO] am getting NULL.

Comment: Update your question with actual data.  You can use `COALESCE(col, 0)` to replace `NULL` values with zero.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim it Works.
Syntax

```
COALESCE((SELECT vouchernumber,
   CASE WHEN vouchernumber LIKE 'A%' OR vouchernumber LIKE 'B%' THEN -1*Quantity
        WHEN vouchernumber LIKE 'C%' THEN 0 END),0)
```

FROM TEMP